# How do I power a scavenged motor?

Tags: power, dc-motor

I found the guts of a paper shredder in an office supply store dumptster.  It's 120vdc. I'm clueless when it comes to anything that isn't powered by a 9v.  Do I need a transformer to power it?

I apologize for the amateurish question.  I couldn't get a good answer googling

Comment: What are you trying to do with it?

Answer (score 4):

You need something that will provide 120V DC.

That could be as simple as a diode between it and the mains (in the US), but that could be a little dangerous...

Personally I'd have a 1:1 isolating transformer (or 2:1 if you're in the UK/europe) to separate it from the mains (pull apart a shaving socket for one of those) and then a rectifier circuit (multiple diodes).

Oh, and don't forget a fuse ;)

The motor will most probably have originally been wired up with 2 diodes like this:

[image: Bi-directional motor control]

Where the switch S1 selects between one of two diodes (middle position is off) to set the direction of the motor for forward (shred) or reverse (jam clear).

Comment: I would think it more likely that an AC-powered device would use a universal motor.  DC wouldn't be impossible (though I think a full-wave bridge rectifier would be more likely than the half-wave circuit you drew) but AC would seem easier.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it really wants 120V *DC*?  That's a strange number since that's not what you get when rectifying the AC line directly, and when there is a conversion required, usually lower voltages are used.  120V sounds like regular AC wall power here in North America, although it's AC of course.

Have you tried running this motor at all?  What makes you think it wants 120V DC?

Comment: While likely a valid and good point, I think this should be a comment at the original question. It is definitely not an answer to the question which is: What to do so the motor will run?

Comment: Shredder motors are very often DC as they need to be able to run backwards to clear paper jams.  This is most easily done with an AC power source, a switch, a couple of diodes, and a DC motor.  See this: http://twitpic.com/5o9mmh/full

Comment: The normal way to design a reversible motor to be driven by AC used to be to use a universal motor with a reversing switch on one set of windings.  Is that no longer the case?

Comment: Agree with @supercat that this is much cheaper to do. You really don't need DC to make a motor which can turn both ways.

Comment: @stevenvh: Rectifiers are pretty cheap; the advantage of universal motors is that they can achieve high torque without needing fancy alloy magnets.  Indeed, series-wound motors have pretty amazing torque characteristics at low speeds; their biggest problems are (1) without some sort of clutch arrangement, a motor whose running torque is adequate may have a stall torque high enough to break things; (2) without some type of load that increases with speed (e.g. a fan), a motor which runs fast enough when loaded may run so fast unloaded that it flies to pieces.

Comment: @stevenvh: A shunt-wound motor would have performance characteristics somewhat more like those of a permanent-magnet motor, but without needing fancy allow magnets.  I would expect that one could design a motor with two sets of windings around the stator--one in series and one in parallel--and end up with performance characteristics that blended those of series- and shunt-wound motors, but I'm not sure how often that's done.  BTW, to control speed and direction of a series-wound motor one can use a DPDT center-off switch; for a shunt-wound motor, one also needs a separate on/off contact.